# Deploy Resharper plugin to users without SDK installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resharper, resharper-plugins

I wrote a Resharper plugin that seems to only work when users have the Resharper SDK installed. Is there a way to package the required libraries into the plugin dll, so that users just need to drop the dll in their Resharper Plugin directory for Visual Studio to recognize it?

Comment: Is it necessary to package as a single dll? If so, ILMerge.exe might help you package any dependencies into your dll. Here's different technique to the same end: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx, which seems like the nifiest way to package in the missing libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to package the libraries, only your plugin. If it's not working, check it on the `Plugins` options page, see if it's loaded. There's a developer log link on the bottom of the page.

Comment: After further examination, it seems that the plugin is recognized, but the ContextAction only works when they build the dll themselves. Do you have any idea why that might be the case?

Comment: Matthew, I don't know, can I take a look at your source code?

Comment: Dmitri helped me with my issue - it turned out to be quite unrelated to ReSharper. The users of my dll simply had to unblock the dll before using it, via Properties -> Unblock.

Answer (score -2):

This may not be a solution to exactly your problem, but within the "References" virtual folder in the project, if you go to properties to one of the references you have the property of "Copy Local", which will copy the DLL to the output directory.  If you do this for all references that come from the SDK, it might work.

I did this for a web server that didn't have asp.net MVC installed, yet my project was.

EDIT: Set the property to *true*

Comment: No, you definitely should not do this.

Comment: Fact is, if you set copy local = true, you'll get a million exceptions. This is explained explicitly in the Troubleshooting section here http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/1.3+Project+Set-Up+%28R7%29